Securely store credentils in Power BI Custom connector
I am trying to build a customer connector to an external API from power BI. I have completed the building part but struggling to store the keys securely so that it is not inside the code in plain text.
What are the options that I have to securely store then inside Power BI and retrieve them during run time.
Thanks a ton for your help.
